# GridView items are grey out after clicking when using bigger images

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, gridview, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader 1.9.2 in a GridView. It worked awesome when I used 75x75 images for my grid items, but I have just changed to bigger images (150x150) to provide better quality and it has a really strange and annoying behaviour:

- the GridView is rendered, all images are shown
- I click on any cell to launch a detail Activity
- when I come back from that Activity, the image I clicked is gone (grey out)
- waiting, invalidating or scrolling the GridView doesn't work. The only way to show that cell back is forcing a reloading.

Could it be a configuration issue? I searched and used many different options but nothing worked. If I switch back to 75x75 images the issue is gone, but I want to use bigger images. Any suggestion please?

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .threadPoolSize(3)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 3)
            .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(3 * 1024 * 1024))
            .diskCache(
                    new LruDiscCache(cacheDir,
                            new HashCodeFileNameGenerator(),
                            32 * 1024 * 1024))
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
            .build();

    mDisplayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2).considerExifParams(true)
                .delayBeforeLoading(50).build();
```

I also tried to increase the cache size, but it didn't worked. I'm testing on Nexus 4 and 7 with Android 4.4.4 but it also happens on any Android 4 device.

Thanks!

Comment: Try increasing your cache size

Comment: Thanks! I did it, but it doesn't work. I doubled the cache size, but the bug is still there.